# Creating matrix with `Array.new(n, Array.new)`

Tags: ruby, arrays

I created an array by doing the following:

```
@gameboard = Array.new(3, Array.new(3, " "))
```

I tried to assign a value like so, and I got this:

```
@gameboard[0][2] = "X"
@gameboard #=> [[" ", " ", "X"], [" ", " ", "X"], [" ", " ", "X"]]
```

When I declare the array differently,

```
@gameboard = [[" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "]]
```

I get this result:

```
@gameboard[0][2] = "X"
@gameboard # => [[" ", " ", "X"], [" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "]]
```

Why does using the `Array.new` method illicit different behavior when assigning values to the array?

Comment: (I am *sure* there is a duplicate of this question.)

Comment: I definitely tried searching, I couldn't find another entry about this. Sorry if it's a duplicate!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow the code:

```
@gameboard = Array.new(3, Array.new(3, " "))
@gameboard.map { |a| a.object_id }
# => [76584030, 76584030, 76584030]
```

means [`new(size=0, obj=nil)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-new) method creates an array of `size`, having the same `ob`.

But [`new(size) {|index| block }`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-new) method works in a different way; it creates an array of `size`, having different `obs`.

See the code below:

```
@gameboard = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3, " ") }
@gameboard.map { |a| a.object_id }
# => [75510080, 75509920, 75509540]
```

The above is the same as your second code example:

```
@gameboard = [[" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "]]
@gameboard.map { |a| a.object_id }
# => [80194090, 80193400, 80193080]
```

If you change or update the the value at index `1` of the first element array of `@gameboard`, it wouldn't affect all other inner array elements.

```
@gameboard = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3, " ") }
@gameboard[0][1] = 2
@gameboard
# => [[" ", 2, " "], [" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "]]
```

Comment: +1 I had just pasted in `@gameboard.map(&:object_id)` when your answer showed :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Tomorrow is weekend.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`Array` constructor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-new) will not duplicate the object you passed; it will reuse the object to fill the array.

Use the block form in order to create a new object for each index:

```
@gameboard = Array.new(3) { |i| Array.new(3) { |j| " " } }
```